# Web components SSR (server side rendering) without headless browser?

Tags: web-component

I would like to build an app using  Webcomponents  , but I'm wondering whether that means that I cannot use server side rendering (for the web components=, unless I use some headless browser such as puppeteer. Since I mainly want to use SSR for performance reasons,using a headless browser does not look like a good option to me. 
Skatejs attempted to render web components server side, but I cannot get the example working.

https://github.com/skatejs/skatejs/issues/1576 
It also looks like skatejs has not been maintained since a while and might therefore not be a good option anyway.

Is rendering web-components server side without a headless browser really feasible as of today?

Comment: What are your motivations for wanting to use Web Components? Don't get me wrong, I am a huge (native) Custom Elements fan. **IF** performance really, *really?*, really!! is an issue, maybe try [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) (or actually the SSR version [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev/)) We use Svelte for rapid prototyping, the [Svelte online REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world) is GREAT to share prototypes with customers. But thus far we have always re-written Svelte code to native Custom Elements code (because it is a W3C standard and will last longer than jQuery did)

Comment: How did you achieve SSR with puppeteer? For me, puppeteer does not render the shadow DOM when I call `page.content()`